# angularjs 'back' inside iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an angularjs project that is opened inside an iframe. Currently when someone hits back I use 'window.history.back();' however it seems this makes the parent window go back.

Using angular how can I make only the content inside the iframe move back?

Comment: Are they on the same domain?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The iframe is on a separate domain.